# Use of Shopping Cart for iOS in-app purchases?

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, shopping-cart

We are creating an iOS app (child/education) and would like to use a shopping cart concept for in-app purchases.

Users will select multiple in-app purchases simultaneously and have the total be added together in a shopping cart.

Will this be approved by Apple?

Comment: don't amazon and ebay do this?

Comment: No, they don't do IAP.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback - think it would be challenging to go around Apple on this one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is *possible*. But it is not practical. The user will still need to click on each individual item (even after being added to the cart) and be prompted to purchase it one by one. This is because you do not control the "checkout process" of an in-app purchase.

When you purchase an in-app item, a prompt will ALWAYS come up stating something like "Do you want to purchase one XXX for $0.99?" Basically it's sending a request to the server saying this user wants to purchase XXX item. So for every in-app purchase item you've registered on iTunes Connect, the user must purchase it one by one. This is an Apple mandated process, there's no way around it unfortunately.

Comment: Thank you! This is what we assumed was true, but the explanation is helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can create an app that has in-app purchases. And for your second question, you would be able to do it depending on how you code your app all together. Here is more of a detailed instruction provided by apple. click [here](https://developer.apple.com/in-app-purchase/In-App-Purchase-Guidelines.pdf)

Answer (score 0):

If you create a shopping cart you will have to do an IAP for each item in the shopping cart or you will have to create IAP's for all combinations of things that a user could buy to have one purchase at checkout.  I would suggest just doing IAP when the user would have added it their shopping cart.